# `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` error when converting WPF project to .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-5

I am converting a WPF project from `Framework 4.6.2` to `.NET 5.0`. After I convert (using `try-convert` without error) and I try to build I get the following:

> Error MC1000  Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 'System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' in assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Web.dll'.'   MyWPFControlLibrary C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets   240

The error is straightforward but I'm not referencing `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` anywhere in my code (at least I don't think I am). It's not an ASP.NET project and I've even tried doing a plain-text search on every file in the project and cannot find anything referencing that, and I don't think it's inherited anywhere. There are two referenced projects in this WPF project but I've already successfully converted both those projects to `.NET 5.0`.

Any help is appreciated. I've tried every forum post I can find and at this point I'm tempted to just create a new project and copy over each class manually although that would take ages.

Comment: Any luck with this? Same issue with upgrade to .NET 6.

Comment: @faldeland Nope. I created a new solution, created new projects, and literally copied over the code. It took me two days and was a huge PITA but it worked.